# add by author to front page (static page)

Tags: wordpress

I am using the 2021 theme. My front page does not display By Author. But By Author shows up in single post page. Is there a way to add By Author to front page? I can post a link to my website and code if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Robert, a simple solution would be to open the file:

> wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone/inc/template-tags.php

and go to line 131 and paste the following piece of code there:

```
echo  '<a href="' . esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ) . '" rel="author">' . esc_html( get_the_author() ) . '</a>';
```

Note, this will work with 2021 theme. I did not test this on other Wordpress default templates.

Comment: The function is called twenty_twenty_one_posted_by(); I added the code to line 84. Thank you!